# how to ensure the thread spawned by an activity keeps alive after user hit back button?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a list view in activity A and the detail view of list item in activity B, now I start a thread in activity B to download a zip file from internet then I hit the back button. How to ensure that the thread will keep alive until it finish downloading? 
I have check the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969324/how-to-check-if-a-thread-spawned-by-an-activity-is-alive-after-the-activity-has), but I m not sure if the thread will die when the system is in short of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Download the file using a service.

Comment: Thank you for helping, but Please make sure this should be a comment!

Comment: @RDC Thank you for pointing me that. I didn't realize that i have crossed 50 rep.

Comment: thanks, but what if I HAVE TO create a thread in activity B, what could be the solution?